# Implement linq filters in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, linq, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I have a web forms application, which has a page with a Telerik RadGrid. This grid is bound using the NeedDataSource event and I have changed most of the columns to CustomFilteringColumns. In one of them I am using a line like this one:

```
((GridFilteringItem) ((filterControl).Parent)).FireCommandEvent("Filter", new  Pair("Custom", "Price"));
```

to filter the orders that this grid contains. Since there are quite a few of them /more than 1000/ I get an error ‘Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.’

I understand that one possible way to fix that is to use a linq query with a where clause, which will serve as a filter.

My questions are: what is the best way to solve this problem? If it is using linq, how should I implement this filter?

Comment: Yes you can use LINQ to filter underlying DataTable; I don't have a RadGrid example, but here's how it is done in Infragistics UltraWebGrid: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2012/03/07/totally-custom-filter-for-ultrawebgrid-using-linq/ maybe you will find it usefull.  Or even more basic example: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2012/03/06/replace-datatable-rowfilter-with-linq/

Comment: I'll assume this is what you are looking for : http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-operate-with-filter-expression-manually.html . You, however, don't provide enough code to make an educated guess regarding a solution. Sorry :|.

Comment: Trekstuff - Thank you very much for the useful information. I needed someone to point me in the right direction. RadGrid has no RowFilterApplying event, but maybe I can use the OnItemCommand one. KreepN - I have read the telerik documentation and I am already using the information in your link to construct a filter. However this type of filtering seems pretty slow when operating on numerous records. Thank you for your help though.